# Animate radius change in mapbox/leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have drawn a circle using L.circle.I want to change the radius with a smooth animation?

Answer (score 3):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x060L103/2/

```
var circle = L.circleMarker([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 5}).addTo(map);


var newRadius = 200;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   var currentRadius = circle.getRadius();
   console.debug("currentRadius", currentRadius);
   if (currentRadius < newRadius) {
       circle.setRadius(++currentRadius);
       console.debug("new Radius", circle.getRadius());
   } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 1);
```

Just modify the function passed to the interval to take radius as argument for example.

### Edit (Add the fiddle as a snippet inside the answer)

```js
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.5, 30.5], 5);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location
var circle = L.circleMarker([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 5}).addTo(map);


var newRadius = 200;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   var currentRadius = circle.getRadius();
   console.debug("currentRadius", currentRadius)
   if (currentRadius < newRadius) {
       circle.setRadius(++currentRadius);
       console.debug("new ", circle.getRadius())
   } else {
       clearTimeout(interval);
   }
}, 1);
```

```css
#map { 
    height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work..there's no while loop here.So it won't increase till the new radius.And even if we add while loop,the transformation is not smooth

Comment: Of course there is no for loop. this is javascript! You cannot animate in a "loop".  It uses setTimeout to increment the radius until the target size is reached. It looks smooth enough in the jsfiddle.
This should be the accepted answer. 
Of course, there are many techniques to animate in javascript, but this is the simplest way.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed using interval is the way to go for me, you could try to do that with plain CSS but as Leaflet is already setting itself a lot of style properties like transform, I would be really careful doin that. And you can make it smoother (or not) by decreasing the incremental value for example, by increasing the radius by 0.1 at each step instead of 1